# how to migrate old fedora directory server to new server

Tags: 389-ds

I have and old fedora 4 running fedora directory server, now I have to migrate all the database, schema to a new host running fedora 12 with 389 dir server.

I wanna know how to do it, how to export all the information from the old machine and import to the new one.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/dir-server/MigrateFromSun.html above doc steps which use for my RedHat DS to move new box!! may be it help you